# Failed to create pdf file

Tags: errors, miktex, conversion, texniccenter

My sister is currently writing her thesis and at mid work an error occurred at creating the pdf file. Since I don't have that much experience with Latex myself I can't really help her much with it.

She is using TexnicCenter and after compiling the file Adobe says the pdf file is corrupt and can't be opened. I searched through the MikTex log files  and found the error

```
2016-01-16 17:24:41,738+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Conversion from UTF-8 byte sequence to wide character string did not succeed.
2016-01-16 17:24:41,748+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2016-01-16 17:24:41,748+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Utils\Utils.cpp
2016-01-16 17:24:41,748+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1180
```

I hope anyone can help us with this since the deadline is due soon. :P

File: http://www.file-upload.net/download-11216959/Zula.tex.html

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The error message is useful, but the code would be much more useful. (Nice nickname, incidentally :D)

Comment: i added the link to the file

Comment: On first trial compilations: A `\mathval` typo (should be \mathcal` and `\inU...` which must be `\in U` most likely. But a lot of other errors too. Sorry, but I don't believe this **just** stopped to compile. There are so many errors that can't come just of nothing

Comment: As i said, it stopped working mid work :P I didnt really have the time yet to help her with it so she just kept on writing... But even when i say "stop compiling at Latex errors" it wouldnt do so. The only error i would get is that miktex didnt succeed check the log files... Unless i copy it to a new file, there i get 600 something errors^^ And since she doesnt use a version control i cant check the file when it last worked... 

You think correcting those errors resolves it?

Comment: And she never considered to fix the errors? (Auf gut deutsch: Wie kann man nur?)

Comment: Correcting errors resolves the most problems ;-)

Comment: See my comment below, it was just the naming of the included graphic files... I split the document into pieces until i found the lines the error occured. Took me some time to see it though. :D Anyway thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

Well... Lets say she is not used to Linux paths and named her images with ä,ü,ö etc... This created the errors since it could not load the pictures.

So yeah, this problem is solved, her latex errors she corrects herself! :P Thank you for the help anyway and have a nice evening! :)

Comment: Note that if you use characters outside US-ASCII (such as ä,ü,ö) in an argument to `\graphicspath{}` command you would get the same problem.