# Biber fails to run

Tags: biblatex, errors, biber, zotero

I'm currently in the process of finishing my bachelor thesis but I'm runnning into some trouble with referencing. For some reason whenever I try to cite anything TexStudio freezes up for a few seconds and then greets my with an error message. I did successfully build and compile documents with a bibliography (exported from Zotero) before and never encountered this problem until now. After reinstalling both the latest TexLive distribution and TexStudio the problem persists. Documents that compile seamlessly before now freeze up and i got these errors:

```
    No file galvanik_pressler_marzemin.bbl.
    Citation 'shen_growth_2008' on page 9 undefined
    Overfull \hbox (33.48036pt too wide) in paragraph
    Empty bibliography
    There were undefined references.
    Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) galvanik_pressler_marzemin(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

The messages while running build&view are these

    Process started: biber.exe "galvanik_pressler_marzemin"

    Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "galvanik_pressler_marzemin".tex

    Process exited normally
```

So I do know for a fact that Biber was run. I really don't know why it's acting up. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I found a local backup of the original untouched document files that I compiled one of my latest protocols with (including bibliogrpahy). When I tried to build&view again, the document didn't compile and I got these errors.

```
Use of \sortlist doesn't match its definition. \sortlist{
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \sortlist{none}
Undefined control sequence. \entry{shen_growth_2008}{article}{}
Undefined control sequence. \endentry
Undefined control sequence. \endentry
Extra \endgroup. \begin{document}

Citation 'shen_growth_2008' on page 10 undefined
Overfull \hbox (33.48036pt too wide) in paragraph
Empty bibliography
There were undefined references.
Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) galvanik_pressler_marzemin(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Also, the .bbl file tells my this

```
% $ biblatex auxiliary file $
% $ biblatex bbl format version 2.5 $
% Do not modify the above lines!
%
% This is an auxiliary file used by the 'biblatex' package.
% This file may safely be deleted. It will be recreated by
% biber as required.
%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}
  {\@latex@error
     {Missing 'biblatex' package}
     {The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.}
      \aftergroup\endinput}
  {}
\endgroup
```

What the hell is going on here?

EDIT2:

I deleted the old .bbl file from the original files and tried to run again. It eventually compiled after 30 seconds but the citation was screwed up and no .bbl file was created. The .blg file shows this

```
[0] Config.pm:324> INFO - This is Biber 2.1
[0] Config.pm:327> INFO - Logfile is 'galvanik_pressler_marzemin.blg'
[51] biber-MSWIN:273> INFO - === %a %b %e, %Y, %H:%M:%S
[52] Biber.pm:333> INFO - Reading 'galvanik_pressler_marzemin.bcf'
[263] Biber.pm:645> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[304] Biber.pm:2977> INFO - Processing section 0
[343] Biber.pm:3115> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'galvanik_prot.bib' for section 0
[356] bibtex.pm:1021> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[364] bibtex.pm:895> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'galvanik_prot.bib'
[409] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[409] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[409] Biber.pm:2854> INFO - Sorting list 'none' of type 'entry' with scheme 'none' and locale 'de-DE'
[409] Biber.pm:2858> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de-DE'
[411] bbl.pm:505> INFO - Writing 'galvanik_pressler_marzemin.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[423] bbl.pm:596> INFO - Output to galvanik_pressler_marzemin.bbl
```

EDIT 3:

I tried running a minimal setup (standard bibliography in Texstudio was Biber) using [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95599839/biblio_test.bib) (bib file with 1 entry on my dropbox) bibliography and this code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}% Recommended
\usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}

% \bibliography{<mybibfile>}% ONLY selects .bib file; syntax for version <= 1.1b
\addbibresource{biblio_test.bib}% Syntax for version >= 1.2

\begin{document}

A bare citation command: \cite{liu_class_2014}.

A citation command for use in the flow of text: As \textcite{liu_class_2014} said \dots

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

After a minute of waiting the error log was

```
No file test.bbl.
Citation 'liu_class_2014' on page 1 undefined
Citation 'liu_class_2014' on page 1 undefined
Empty bibliography
There were undefined references.
Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) test(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Am I screwed?

EDIT 4:

Uploaded a [test folder](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95599839/test.zip) for Ulrike. Thanks for being patient!

EDIT 5:

It seems like it was indeed a compatibility issue with biber and biblatex. I managed to get it working again after a complete reformat and installing a complete MikTex distr and Texstudio. Compiling worked again after deleting all the files except for the .tex files.

EDIT 6:

The problem I mentioned a few comments down with not being able to compile one specific document after doing a full reinstall was due to umlauts in some file names. After editing them it worked again.

Comment: Delete the cache folder mentioned in the error message and try again.

Comment: I just did that, didn't help. I tried using a bibliography file from another document that I know compiles and I was greeted with another error message. Could it be that the code in my bachelor thesis is faulty?

Comment: Welcome, If you just started, i would recommend an update of `biblatex` and `biber` with the package manger of your distribution (MikTeX or TeX Live).

Comment: Currently doing a full reinstall of TeX Live and TeXStudio. Thanks for the answers, you guys are giving me hope again :)

Comment: Okay, I have reinstalled everything and tried again. I'm now getting this message when I'm trying to compile

Process started: bibtex.exe "bakkarbeit_simon"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: bakkarbeit_simon.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file bakkarbeit_simon.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file bakkarbeit_simon.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file bakkarbeit_simon.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)

Comment: You need to run biber not bibtex.

Comment: Sadly I'm getting nowhere. I installed the latest Texlive distribution and updated biber and biblatex. I then reinstalled Texstudio and checked that the standard bibliography is Biber. I then tried to compile an old document with some bibliography and it won't even compile the damn thing. Is there any way to upload some logs in these comment replies? I'm getting real desperate, all the reinstalling made it worse and I have no idea what's the root of the problem. Been using Latex for 2 years now.

Comment: You can edit the question and add log-files.

Comment: I have updated the original post, hopefully someone can make something of it.

Comment: Show the content of the   .blg file.

Comment: I tried to compile the original files that worked 3 months ago again and it showed me error messages. I added it to the main post.

Comment: Show the blg file, not the bbl. And as you now have a newer biblatex you should delete older bbl files and recompile everything anew to avoid errors.

Comment: added to the main post

Comment: I tried running a minimal setup and it failed. I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Well it would be good if you would stop to change your setup every 5 minutes. How should one help you if log-files, blg-files and error messages are all from different stages? Add to your example `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (assuming the file is in utf8). Put it together with your example bib in an empty folder. Compile it (make sure that you run pdflatex, biber and pdflatex), then make a zip of the whole folder and put it somewhere on the net for inspection.

Comment: I edited it into the main post :)

Comment: Removing `test.aux` from the zip file's `test` folder (which contained an undefined control sequence) and running `latexmk -pdf` compiled without errors, including `biber` runs. I have Biber 2.1 and a MacPorts-based TeXLive 2015 distribution with `biblatex` 3.0. The documentation of `biblatex` specifies which versions of Biber and `biblatex` work together. Your `biblatex` version seems to be 3.4. What does `biber --version` output?

Comment: There is no blg in the zip, so you didn't run biber.

Comment: Does your file name contain special characters? Try avoiding spaces (should not be necessary) and non-ASCII chars as well as other special characters. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287923/35864

Comment: Oh god. Again a new system. You had a running texlive 2016, and now you have miktex. I'm giving up. I don't want to waste my time trying to help you to adjust your miktex system only to find out that in the mean time you have erased everything again.

Comment: Ulrike, thanks for taking so much time, I really appreciate it. The thing is, I can't just sit around the whole day and do nothing about the problem, I want to finish my thesis. That's why I tried different things. It really seems like it was a compitibility issue between biber and biblatex, the problem vanished after a clean MikTeX and TeXStudio install. I also figured out the problem with the one document that dind't want to compile. It was some umlauts in some file names. 

Again thanks for the time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You removed the previous question content, thus invalidating the context of an existing answer. Better roll that edit back. Any new question should go to a new thread. Happy TeXing!

Comment: Yes, I deleted a few lines because I couldn't add a third link which rendered the first like useless. Figured a few minutes later that it might've been better to leave it there anyway. Is there a way to rollback to a previous edit? If not, I'm just gonna write a summary about the problem for the people who might have the same problem.

Comment: There is the *edited* link centered below the question. It allows rollbacks.

Comment: Spending the whole day to deinstall and reinstall software doesn't push forward your thesis. It would have been much more senseful to write on your thesis and simply ignore the bibliography problem while waiting for help. Beside this: I told you that the test folder doesn't contain a biber blg only 20 minutes after you uploaded it -- which means that your texlive 2016 probably was fine, you simply didn't try it out correctly --, and so the time to install miktex was simply wasted.

Comment: You might be right Ulrike. Thing is I did actually run pdflatex and biber separately in the order you told me to. It didn't work and didn't create a biber blg file. At least that's what I figured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a `biblatex`/`biber` compatibility issue. You seem to have `biblatex` 3.4 and `Biber` 2.1. The documentation of [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) mentions

> ### 1.5.5 Compatibility Matrix for `biber`
>
> `biber` versions are closely coupled with `biblatex` versions.
>   You need to have the right combination of the two.
>   `biber` will throw a fatal error during processing
>   if it encounters information which comes from a `biblatex` version
>   which is incompatible.
>   Table 1 shows a compatibility matrix for the recent versions.

And according to that table 1, `biblatex` 3.4 is best paired with `biber` 2.5.

Comment: Mhh, the OP did an update of TeX live and is (apparently) running TeX live 2016 now. The logs that showed Biber 2.1 are from before the update, I believe. Normally TeX live does not cause version problems, Biber and `biblatex` are updated simultaneously.

Comment: I had a similar issue in 2014 because my MacPorts-based TeXLive installation had `biblatex` and `biber` in separate packages without strict version dependency specifications. But it's still a guess.

Comment: I think that's actually what caused it. Today I completely reformatted my computer and installed a complete MikTeX distribution and TexStudio. Compiling worked again once i deleted all the files except for the .tex file.

Funny thing is, all my latex documents compile fine except for one which doesn't even contain any bibliogrpahies. I will edit it into the main post, maybe you know something about it. Thanks so far, you're great!