# Conversion from UTF-8 byte sequence to wide character string did not succeed

Tags: miktex, unicode

MiKTeX (on windows) stopped working. It gives this message:
"Conversion from UTF-8 byte sequence to wide character string did not succeed."
launching the wizards.

Comment: Welcome to TeX. Can you show us the code resulting in your error?

Comment: Thanks. It gives me the error even by launching the MikTeX wizards. And of course, not even a basic code can be compiled.

Comment: possible relation with this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287923/failed-to-create-pdf-file (may be some characters outside US-ASCII (such as ä,ü,ö) ) or something similar. Delete aux files of that project before open MiKTeX.

Comment: Another think to try is `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage{textcomp}` that have solved similar problems

Comment: It didn't help. Excuse my ignorance, but I don's see how aux files may prevent MikTeX wizards from launching!

Comment: Here, it happens during an installation with `basic-miktex-2.9.6643-x64`. Just start the installation and install to  `D:\MíKTeX` (not the UTF-8 character after the first M). So, ensure you do not do any typos during setting the installation path manually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the origin of this problem, but it also happens to me from time to time. I know it is not related to any package issue or any input characters because the error message appears the moment I hit the "compile" button.

Every time, the problem disappears when restarting Windows.